# Multiple residence permit

Tags: germany, resident-permit, italy

I am a non-EU person with researcher residence permit in Italy. While, my wife had a Blue card in Germany. Though, I can travel to Germany on my residence permit however, I want to apply residence permit in Germany for myself and a residence permit of Italy for my wife.

**Questions**

- As far as I understood, I can have multiple residence permit, can
  some one confirm this?
- Give this scenario, can someone suggest a
  better option?

Comment: No idea how this scenario would be delt with. The question that will be asked is why the 90/180 days rule is not sufficient? This question needs more clarification as to why a second residence permit is **needed**, when the spouse will not be residing but only visiting.

Comment: we both temporary contracts, in case of contract completion, the second permit would be helpful to stay with the spouse.

Comment: If your contract ends in Italy and the Blue Card contract in Germany is still active a spouse residence permit will be issued. For Italy I don't know the details for **researcher residence permit** if a spouse permit is automatically allowed.